# Java 8 Mapping a list of maps grouping by a key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have the following: `List<Map<String, Object>>`. I want to obtain a `Map<String, List<Object>` using streams. The key of this map will be the key, that it is repeated in the list. Basically, is a one-to-many, this would be an example of the data:

```
[
    { id: "a", name: "AAA"}
    { id: "a", name: "BBB"}
    { id: "b", name: "XXX"}
    { id: "b", name: "YYY"}
]
```

And I would like to obtain:

```
{
    a: ["AAA", "BBB"],
    b: ["XXX", "YYY"]
}
```

So, this new map is grouping by id from the previous list.

Comment: IMO use object instead of `Map` due to it would be simple the process. `class MyObject{ String id; String name;}` and  use following code to achieve final result: `list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId, Collectors.mapping(MyObject::getName, Collectors.toList())));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` along with `Collectors.mapping`:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = listOfMaps.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> map.get("id").toString(),
                                   Collectors.mapping(map -> map.get("name"),
                                                      Collectors.toList())));
```

`Collectors.groupingBy` creates the map you want, while `Collectors.mapping` adapts a collector into another one by applying a mapping function to each element of the stream. (In this case, it collects to a list by first transforming each map of the stream to the value mapped to the `"name"` key).

If needed, the code above might be modified to skip maps that don't have an entry with the `"id"` key:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = listOfMaps.stream()
    .filter(map -> map.get("id") != null))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> map.get("id").toString(),
                                   Collectors.mapping(map -> map.get("name"),
                                                      Collectors.toList())));
```